# Flutter Web shimmer effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I tried to implement shimmer effect in flutter web using plug in https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer.

But it is throwing following error.

```
The following UnimplementedError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
UnimplementedError

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 214:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/surface/scene_builder.dart 234:5           pushShader
```

Is it possible to implement shimmer effect in flutter web using this plug in?

Sample Code which works on mobile but throws error on web.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                baseColor: Colors.red,
                highlightColor: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text(
                  'Shimmer',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mobile Screen

[image]

Error on Web

[image]

Comment: Show your code of how you tried to use the plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_shimmer/tree/master/example This is the code i am trying to run on chrome

Comment: Yes it has support for web

Comment: @M123 is there any working code? which version of flutter is supported?

Comment: @max I dont really know, I have never worked with this package. Please edit your question and provide more infos, then I can try to help you

Comment: @M123 Sample minimum code and screenshot have been added.

Comment: Consider posting all text as text in a code block. That includes code/errors/data. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also consider reading [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that this post already went through the re-open queue due to your first edit. It will not be pushed into the queue again from another edit. But an edit may make someone notice and push it in with a reopen vote.